# Creating a cross platform application for a local sports club

Tags: android, ios, flutter, react-native

I need to create a cross platform application for a local sports club. The main features are:
Members of the sports club should be able to log in and rsvp for sporting events like practices and tournaments.
There should be an attendance record for each member and the events they have attended.
Members should receive notifications for events.
Directory with contact information of all members.

Admin login should have additional features:
View attendance records for all members.
Add sporting events.
Add photos to the gallery.
Setup notifications for RSVP deadlines.

This app is for a college project so it does not need to be perfect. I am thinking of using flutter or react native for this and I am computer science student but I haven't used either software before. What would you guys recommend to do? How should I approach this project if I have 2 weeks to finish it? Are there any projects on github I can use?

I have tried searching online for youtube tutorials but I can't find anything that matches the kind of app that I want to build.

Comment: If you don't know how to build the app then you may start to learn it. But it will take much more than 2 weeks. So the only one solution I can suggest is to outsource it to somebody experienced enough.

Answer (score 1):

### It depends

As someone who has now worked with both Flutter and React Native now (Mostly Flutter), I recommend:

1. React Native, if you like JavaScript, HTML & CSS.
2. Flutter, if you are more comfortable with Java or is a complete beginner. It has types, null safety, and is more friendly for new developers. The productivity is much better with flutter, since there are types on variables and null safety. This means, that you almost always gets the warnings in your IDE, but mostly never when running the application. If you choose Flutter, Android Studio is my preffered IDE.

Also, it is worth noting, that iOS Development works almost only with a Mac. I say "almost", since you can use "Expo Go" to test your application on an iPhone with React Native. However, since you want to send Push Notifications, it can only be enabled through Xcode and with a Developer Certificate (for iOS) anyway. That way a Mac is basically needed for Cross Platform Development.

Also also, no matter, which one you choose, it will take quite some time to develop an app.

### Courses

Good sources for courses on YouTube is NetNinja. I personally used his "Flutter for beginners" and "Flutter Firebase" in 2020. His courses are kind of outdated now, because Flutter has improved by getting null-safety. So you might run into trouble there. However, he has a good React Native course, that seems to be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both. I will choose **ReactNative** because it uses JavaScript you can find more sources and examples on the web. Later on, your JavasScript skills can be utilized in other frameworks **BE** or **FE**. If you go with **Flutter** you will have to learn **Dart**. I'm not familiar with the component ecosystem on **Flutter** there might be some UI components/widgets to get you started, but Dart is only used for **Flutter** development, so if you don't plan to become a **Flutter** developer it is pretty much useless. One huge downside of **Flutter** is the way you debug your UI layer, since Flutter is drawing over a blank canvas you don't have a real representation of how your components are laid out on the screen.

**ReactNative** will give you close to native performance, there are a lot of UI Libraries that you can reuse, and it uses **JavaScript**.

Answer (score 0):

- Both Flutter and React Native are great choices for your project.
- For your project, you can follow these steps :

1. Choose either Flutter or React Native based on your familiarity with the technology.
2. Set up the Firebase project for authentication and notifications.
3. Create the necessary screens for your app.
4. Implement the functionality for logging in, RSVPing for events, and tracking attendance.
5. Set up notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging.
   Implement the admin features for managing events, photos, and notifications.